# Weird If statement behaviour inside channel:form

Tags: conditionals, channel-form, ifelse

I'm building a page containing a channel form to allow users to edit their posts, and I thought I'd add an `{if}...{/if}` statement to prevent them editing other users' entries. The permissions on the channel are set correctly, but this was just to get around the error message on form submission. So I added this:

```
{exp:channel:form .... entry_id="{segment_3}"}
  {if author_id <> member_id}
    {redirect="home"}
  {/if}
{/exp:channel:form}
```

The issue then, was that the code redirected even when author_id = member_id. This seemed bizarre, so as a test, I changed the above code to read:

```
{exp:channel:form .... entry_id="{segment_3}"}
  {if author_id <> member_id}
    Not Equals
  {if:else}
    Equals
  {/if}
{/exp:channel:form}
```

and found that regardless of which entry I edit, the statement returned

> Not Equals

Upon a bit more playing around, I found that if I add an `{author_id}` tag above the `{if}...{/if}` statement, it worked properly. It seems that unless I echo the `{author_id}` before the comparison, `{author_id}` is... blank?

Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like expected behaviour. If you're using `{author_id}` in the context of a Channel Form then it is to *submit* and entry into ExpressionEngine. Therefore until you do make a submission the form has no `author_id` even though the entry does. It's a little different to the Channel Entries tag in that respect as that's just retrieving an entry.

By outputting `{author_id}` before the conditional in the same template you're effectively setting a value to be compared. You could get around this by simply setting the `author_id` as a hidden input above the conditional in a similar way as you're doing now, or you could pass it in as an [embed variable](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/embedding.html#embed-variables-for-the-embedded-template).

Looking at what you're trying to achieve however, you could just look to include the  [`author_only="yes"` parameter](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_form/#author-only) to the Channel Form along with a [return parameter](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_form/#return).

```
{exp:channel:form channel="my_channel" entry_id="{segment_3}" author_only="yes" return="template_group/template/ENTRY_ID"}

    ...

{/exp:channel:form}
```

This would then ensure that only the author of the entry can edit it and would fall back to the system Message Pages if the user isn't authorised. *You can then style or control those how you choose but that's another question in itself. :)*